# URL in android studio not responded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am working on a project in android studio, as of now i don't have that much knowledge. in register page for user I used api from 000webhost but it show error like Unexpected response code 500 from "URL".
below is the code

```
package com.example.pakring;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.pakring.databinding.ActivityRegistrationBinding;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Registration extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText name,email,password;
    TextView tvlogin;
    Button btnregisgeter;
    String str_name,str_email,str_password;
    String url = "https://jayvaja11sql.000webhostapp.com/";

    ActivityRegistrationBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityRegistrationBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        binding.tvloginp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this , MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        binding.btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (binding.name.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    binding.name.setError("Please Enter Name");
                }else if (binding.email.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    binding.email.setError("Please Enter Email");
                }else if (binding.password.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    binding.password.setError("Please Enter Password");
                }else {
                    inserData(binding);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void inserData(ActivityRegistrationBinding binding) {

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Registration.this , MainActivity.class));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Nullable
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String , String> map = new HashMap<>();

                map.put("Name" , binding.name.getText().toString());
                map.put("Email" , binding.email.getText().toString());
                map.put("Password" , binding.password.getText().toString());

                return map;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }

}
```

so in above code I am trying to register a user in database using my api which I created in 000webhost.

Any idea why I am getting this error?

Note:- the API works perfectly in postman but not in my application

In above code I have tried retrofit library but not worked properly so now I have used volley for my project. I have also added volley dependency in gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

`http://10.0.2.2:{portNumber}/{endPoint}` try this.